# Adding couple outlets from portable generator wiring to house

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, gfci, generator

I want to add a couple of outlets from a generator to inside of the house to avoid having extension cords running through the door when the power is out.
Similarly to [this product](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/king-canada-generator-home-connection-kit/1001552464?eid=PS_GOOGLE_D28%20-%20E-Comm_GGL_Shopping_PLA_EN_Outdoor%20Power_Outdoor%20Power_PLA_EN__PRODUCT_GROUP_pla-376463613338&gclid=CjwKCAiA7939BRBMEiwA-hX5J7eNUffY2OWKOK6E8TRpuzom3PuNKw5i6fjL6qQ_5-gS-GpjIGcrThoC2sIQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds).

I’ve got a small [portable generator](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B018B420T0/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) with a 30a L5-30r plug on it.
I’ve ordered a L5-30r inlet box plug and 25ft cord to connect generator to house.

My plan is to get some 10/2 wire. 3/4” conduit to run the 10ga into the house to a pair of receptacles.

The generator is fused @ 30a. But the receptacles aren’t rated for 30a. I’m thinking I should run 2x 20a GFCIs to protect the outlets from being overloaded. It’s just for emergency power, fridge, sump, a light or 2 etc.

Is this correct? I was told I should fuse it separately. Do I need a subpanel?

Comment: This is nice. I've got to ask though, do you have an actual question, or are you just sharing your plans? Please take the [tour] to see how this Question & Answer forum differs from general discussion boards.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It looks like you now have two separate accounts; you should [request that they be merged](//diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Comment: Is sending the L5-30 inlet box back and getting a L5-20 inlet box instead an option?

Comment: Your link to the generator is wrong. Doesn't the generator have a 20 amp outlet? Most small generators do. It would make your job a lot easier.

Answer (score 3):

You need a subpanel to do this correctly/safely.

You also need an L5-30P inlet to take an L5-30R cord. Plug goes to Receptacle, and the side that has power needs to be R, while the side that gets power needs to be P.

Since you are not proposing "dual-use" inside receptacles, a small sub-panel that takes your 30A input and has a couple of 20A breakers to feed your receptacles would be sufficient. GFCIs are not breakers (though some breakers are GFCIs) so using 20A GFCIs connected to a 30A input without a 20A breaker in between is not safe nor code-compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Well said by Ecner. I might add that once you figure out the price of doing a subpanel and breakers, you might want to consider that cost against a simple power failure transfer switch in or next to your breaker panel. If the outlets you want to serve with standby power already have a "home run" to the panel, then you can just route them through a transfer switch (with as many poles as you need).

It might be just a little bit more, but worth it.